Which Ubuntu distribution do you think I should use for this old laptop?
I have an Acer Extenca 5680 laptop with Intel core duo and Nvidia g105m,  8GB RAM and 256GB of SSD. Which Ubuntu distro should I use? I want to use a user friendly operating system. Thank you for the suggestions.

And related: How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?

FYI:  I for sure would Try the system in live mode to see how they work on your hardware... You can use different ISOs to explore the kernel stack options (eg. 22.04 media exists using 5 different kernels from 5.15 to 6.8) as on older hardware (esp. GPU) I've found the kernel stack matters; as well as desktop. The oldest device I use in QA for all current releases (inc. oracular which will be 24.10) is a 2005 HP device & desktop chosen (ie. flavor), GPU & kernel stack are what I'd consider need exploring (I have other devices too that are newer, but your NVidia is what I'd explore)
